# ¿Como guardar Excepcion en SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, consola

Buen día.

Realizo una implementación en C#, con SQL Server, donde se realiza la lectura del datos de archivos de texto. Lo que requiero es guardar las excepciones en una tabla, esta deberá guardar la fecha, descripción de la excepción y el nombre del archivo que provoco la excepción:
Tengo el siguiente código, pero no me funciona, busco alguna orientación de como podrái ser o alguna sugerencia.

```
        #region Producto
    //Metodo con arreglo, asigna los datos de cada linea de producto
    public static Productos[] Producto(string startFolder)
    {
        string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        List<string> Datos = LeerArchvioTXT(startFolder);

        Productos[] lineas = new Productos[Datos.Count - 2];
        //FOR para leer los datos de los productos linea por linea
        for (int a = 2; a < Datos.Count; a++)
        {
            try
            {
                char separador = '|';
                string[] DatosCol;
                DatosCol = Datos[a].Split(separador);
                lineas[a - 2].Codigo = DatosCol[2];
                //lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Referencia
                lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Observaciones
                lineas[a - 2].Cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[7]); //Cantidad
                lineas[a - 2].Precio = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[8]); //Precio
                //lineas[a - 2].Impuesto1 = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[4]);//impuesto1
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                conexionbd conexionbd = new conexionbd();
                string sCon = conexionbd.CadenaConexion();
                //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon);

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        string sel = "select RutaEntrada, RutaSalida, RutaError from Rutas_Datos";
                        string insert = "Insert into Prueba(ID_Doc, Detalle_Error, Fecha) values (@archivo, @detalle, @fecha)";
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sel, con);
                        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            string startFold = reader["RutaEntrada"].ToString();
                            // Toma una instantánea del sistema de archivos.  
                            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFold);

                            IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                            //Crea la consulta  
                            IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileQuery =
                                from file in fileList
                                where file.Extension == ".txt"
                                select file;

                            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileQuery)
                            {
                                if (dir.Exists)
                                {
                                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@archivo", fi.Name.ToString());
                                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detalle", ex.Message);
                                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha.ToString());


                                    sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                                    con.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return lineas;
    }
    #endregion
```

La ruta de entrada también es tomada de una tabla de la misma base de datos, es por ello las dos consultas.
Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para mejor, es bienvenida.

Comment: Pero no hace nada en el bloque catch?  Ha usado un logging como Log4Net o elmah?  Despues de todo, si el error es "no puede alcanzar al sirvador SQL", intentando guardarlo en SQL no va a funcionar.

Comment: Esa tabla donde quieres guardar las excepciones, esta local o en un servidor

Comment: Hola @Japv, gracias por la respuesta, es una base local por le momento.

Comment: Leí tu publicación y no encontré ninguna pregunta... ¿estás describiendo un trabajo para que alguien más lo haga por tí o tienes algún problema al tratar de resolver ese problema que describes y olvidaste mencionarlo?

Comment: Hola @Duston, gracias por la respuesta, el error es sobre la estructura del archivo de texto, es decir, si uno de los datos del archivo de texto no corresponde al tipo de dato que valido, manda una excepción "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto", este mensaje es lo que requiero guardar.

Comment: Hola @jachguate, gracias por la respuesta, ya se ha editado.

Comment: Yo no termino de comprender tu duda. si hay un error y lo queres guardar en la base de datos, lo harias en el catch, que ahora esta vacio. Igual veo problemas en tu codigo.. por ejemplo cierras la conexion a la base de datos,pero segun tu codigo no terminaste de mandarle cosas a la misma...

Comment: Las excepciones tienen que guardarse localmente, no en el servidor, ya que si pierdes la conexion al servidor esto generara una excepcion y otra y otra, una cosa es lo que guardas en la base de datos, y otra las excepciones que genera la aplicacion

Comment: El catch no esta vacio, de hecho esta el For, le sigue un Try y sigue el Catch, es ahí donde esta mi intento de guardar la excepción en la base de datos